# Quickest way to return to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I haven't touched Ruby/Rails for about a year now and need a quick reminder: what's the quickest way to update to the latest version of gem, rails, rake, etc? I want to create a new project from scratch on top of the latest versions. Here's what I have now:

```
$ gem --version
1.3.5

$ rails --version
Rails 2.3.5

$ rake --version
rake, version 0.8.7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by downloading [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and use that to install a clean version of Ruby 1.9.2. You can then download the latest version of Rails 3 on top of it and keep your Rails 2 stuff completely separate should you ever need to go back to one of your old Rails 2 projects.

Answer (score 2):

At first, if you do not have [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) installed, I would suggest you to install it. It will help you to manage the different version of Ruby and Gems you want to use.

Then you will find plenty of starting guide on Google, look at one for your system ( [here is one for ubuntu and rails 3.1](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2011/05/using-rvm-to-install-rails-31-on-ubuntu.html) )
Here is another really good for [Mac Os X](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) by Ryan Bigg

Answer (score 2):

Just start by installing RVM, which allows you to have many rubies versions and gemsets, have a look at [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm). It introduces you to RVM and Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. After a bit of experimentation I realised that that best approach was to upgrade my old Rails app to Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9.2.

This means you don't have to deal with different versions (although I use RVM and it is awesome).

The problem is that Rails has changed a bit in the jump from 2 to 3 and I had to learn a bit about new stuff in Rails and Ruby. In the end though I think this was the right approach because I now know how Rails 3 apps work and my old app is using the latest version.